# How to change Streaming rate of the camera?

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I read in the camera mode documentation of Sony Smartglasses that it has a CAMERA_MODE_JPG_STREAM_LOW_RATE in which camera takes still pictures continuously at 7.5fps. How can I change that to have a lower rate?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to set a specific frame rate when doing JPEG streaming unfortunately.  Did you try just using STILL mode and calling requestCameraCapture() to take pictures in the interval you want?